# Problem with Team Collaboration in Publishing site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, publishing-site

My problem with collaboration with my team members is that, when I Edit the page my team collaborator cann't get the and edit it( it Tell that i Checkout the page) and me i doesn't checkit out, so my question is that i want to work together in the same page and edit it together and in the final step merge our modification
is there any solutions ?
Note : I work in a publishing site

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you cannot work simultaneously on a Page.. Once you are editing a Page, its exclusively checked-out to you.. And once you complete the updates, you check-in the page, so its available to other Authors..

Now your team mate can Check-out the page and do his work and check-in again.. You can set Alerts on the Page Item to automatically get notifications on checking-in/checking-out etc.

Comment: but I already try the same experience with a project site , and it give me a simultaneously edit, and at the end it give me a window prompt to merge our edit results

Comment: hmm, maybe I'm not aware of it.. Let's wait for someone else to jump in